# Why does a column remain in DataFrame's index even after it is dropped

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following piece of code:

```
>>> data = pandas.DataFrame({ 'user': [1, 5, 3, 10], 'week': [1, 1, 3, 4], 'value1': [5, 4, 3, 2], 'value2': [1, 1, 1, 2] })
>>> data = data.pivot_table(index='user', columns='week', fill_value=0)
>>> data['target'] = [True, True, False, True]
>>> data
     value1       value2       target
week      1  3  4      1  3  4
user
1         5  0  0      1  0  0   True
3         0  3  0      0  1  0   True
5         4  0  0      1  0  0  False
10        0  0  2      0  0  2   True
```

Now if I call this:

```
>>> 'target' in data.columns
True
```

It returns `True` as expected. However, why does this return `True` as well?

```
>>> 'target' in data.drop('target', axis=1).columns
True
```

How can I **drop a column** from the table **so it's no longer in the index** and the above statement returns `False`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now (pandas 0.19.2), a multiindex will retain all the ever used labels in its structure. Dropping a column doesn't remove its label from the multiindex and it is still referenced in it. See long GH item [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2770).

Thus, you have to workaround the issue and make assumptions. If you are sure the labels you're checking are on a specific index level (level 0 in your example), then one way is to do this:

```
'target' in data.drop('target', axis=1).columns.get_level_values(0)
Out[145]: False
```

If it can be any level, you can use `get_values()` and lookup on the entire list:

```
import itertools as it
list(it.chain.from_iterable(data.drop('target', axis=1).columns.get_values()))
Out[150]: ['value1', 1, 'value1', 3, 'value1', 4, 'value2', 1, 'value2', 3, 'value2', 4]
```

Comment: note in 0.20.0 (approx 1 month), this will be merged in: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15694, which will allow ``data.columns = data.columns.remove_unused_levels()`` to fix this (its not automatic yet, but can mitigate things)

Answer (score 0):

I propose @Jeff's comment as a new Answer.

```
data = data.drop('target', axis=1)
data.columns = data.columns.remove_unused_levels()
```